# can awk replace fields based on separate specification file?

Tags: awk, getline

I have an input file like this:

```
SomeSection.Foo
OtherSection.Foo
OtherSection.Goo
```

...and there is another file describing which object(s) belong to each section:

```
[SomeSection]
Blah
Foo
[OtherSection]
Foo
Goo
```

The desired output would be:

```
SomeSection.2   // that's because Foo appears 2nd in SomeSection
OtherSection.1  // that's because Foo appears 1st in OtherSection
OtherSection.2  // that's because Goo appears 2nd in OtherSection
```

(The numbers and names of sections and objects are variable)

How would you do such a thing in awk?

Thanks in advance,
Adrian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility:

Content of **script.awk** (with comments):

```
## When 'FNR == NR', the first input file is in process.                                                                                                                                                                                     
## If line begins with '[', get the section string and reset the position                                                                                                                                                                           
## of its objects.                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
FNR == NR && $0 ~ /^\[/ {                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        object = substr( $0, 2, length($0) - 2 )                                                                                                                                                                                             
        pos = 0
        next
}

## This section process the objects of each section. It saves them in
## an array. Variable 'pos' increments with each object processed.
FNR == NR {
        arr_obj[object, $0] = ++pos
        next
}

## This section process second file. It splits line in '.' to find second
## part in the array and prints all.
FNR < NR {
        ret = split( $0, obj, /\./ )
        if ( ret != 2 ) {
                next
        }
        printf "%s.%d\n", obj[1], arr_obj[ obj[1] SUBSEP obj[2] ]
}
```

Run the script (important the order of input files, *object.txt* has sections with objects and *input.txt* the calls):

```
awk -f script.awk object.txt input.txt
```

Result:

```
SomeSection.2
OtherSection.1
OtherSection.2
```

---

**EDIT** to a question in comments:

I'm not an expert but I will try to explain how I understand it:

`SUBSEP` is a character to separate indexes in an array when you want to use different values as key. By default is `\034`, although you can modify it like `RS` or `FS`.

In instruction `arr_obj[object, $0] = ++pos` the comma joins all values with the value of `SUBSEP`, so in this case would result in:

```
arr_obj[SomeSection\034Blah] = 1
```

At the end of the script I access to the index using explicity that variable `arr_obj[ obj[1] SUBSEP obj[2]`, but with same meaning that `arr_obj[object, $0]` in previous section.

You can also access to each part of this index splitting it with SUBSEP variable, like this:

```
for (key in arr_obj) {                     ## Assign 'string\034string' to 'key' variable
    split( key, key_parts, SUBSEP )        ## Split 'key' with the content of SUBSEP variable.
    ...
}
```

with a result of:

```
key_parts[1] -> SomeSection
key_parts[2] -> Blah
```

Comment: Can you please explain the last part of your script? I always have a hardest time working with arrays.

Comment: @JaypalSingh: Updated the answer to explain it.

Answer (score 2):

this awk line should do the job:

```
 awk  'BEGIN{FS="[\\.\\]\\[]"}
        NR==FNR{ if(NF>1){ i=1; idx=$2; }else{ s[idx"."$1]=i; i++; } next; }
        { if($0 in s) print $1"."s[$0] } ' f2 input
```

see test below:

```
kent$  head input f2
==> input <==
SomeSection.Foo
OtherSection.Foo
OtherSection.Goo

==> f2 <==
[SomeSection]
Blah
Foo
[OtherSection]
Foo
Goo

kent$  awk  'BEGIN{FS="[\\.\\]\\[]"}
        NR==FNR{ if(NF>1){ i=1; idx=$2; }else{ s[idx"."$1]=i; i++; } next; }
        { if($0 in s) print $1"."s[$0] } ' f2 input
SomeSection.2
OtherSection.1
OtherSection.2
```